# E0126 error with Bluemix CLI cluster creation

Tags: ibm-cloud

My goal is to script the creation of a container cluster with the Bluemix CLI.  The command I am running is:

```
$ bx cs cluster-create --name mycluster --workers 1
```

The messages I get back are:

```
Creating cluster...
The machine-type flag was not specified. So free cluster will be created
FAILED

Your Bluemix space must be specified. If you are using the API, include the headers
X-Auth-Resource-Space header. To get the list of orgs run 'bx iam orgs'.  To get the
list of spaces run 'bx iam spaces'. (E0126)
Incident ID: 421d4577-4873-433d-adff-a870fe0983a3
```

Where I am stuck/confused is that the message seems to say that I specify my Bluemix space, but there isn't an option on this command to specify a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that one must specify both one's organization and space to the environment using a separate command.  Specifically:

```
$ bx target -o <yourOrganization> -s <yourSpace>
```

You can find these values after logging into bluemix using the CLI commands:

```
$ bx iam orgs
```

and

```
$ bx iam spaces
```

Once you have run the `bx target` command, you can re-run the `bx cs create-cluster` command.